# How to obtain the difference between two time fields in hh:mm:ss format?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, field-calculator, attribute-table

I have to 2 date fields in a table, ALARMTIME and ARRIVETIME.  I want to acquire the difference between the two in a new RESPONSE_TIME field in ArcGIS.
The only successful field calculation I could get is the answer in seconds using:
DateDiff ("s", [ALARMTIME], [ARRIVETIME] )
But if I have 8:05:00am - 8:02:32am, I'd like to see 00:02:28 or 02:28 or 2:28 instead of 148 seconds.  Please help.  My response time field is a double.  I couldn't get any calcs to work using a date field.

Comment: Are you comfortable with Python (ArcPy) ?

Answer (score 4):

You can run the following code as shown below, note the table is a geodatabase table, not a shapefile. All fields are Date fields with only the time portion actually set.

[image: Field calculate]

If you are not familiar with python the indentation in the code block is important.

Code Block:

```py
from datetime import datetime
def computeDiff(start,end):
  FMT = '%H:%M:%S'
  tdelta = datetime.strptime(start, FMT) - datetime.strptime(end,FMT)
  return str(tdelta)
```

Expression:

```
computeDiff(!alarmtime!, !arrivetime!)
```

Comment: I ran this code, but my date fields also have AM/PM, which caused an error.  Also, this is a geodatabase table.

Comment: Here is the error message:                                  
ERROR 000539: Error running expression: computeDiff( u"8:02:32 AM" , u"8:05:00 AM" ) 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<expression>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<string>", line 4, in computeDiff
  File "C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.5\Lib\_strptime.py", line 335, in _strptime
    data_string[found.end():])
ValueError: unconverted data remains:  AM
Failed to execute (CalculateField).

Comment: Is it a file geodatabase, and what locality have you got Windows set at?  Look [here](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/manage-data/tables/fundamentals-of-date-fields.htm) in the help file.

Comment: It's a sql server enterprise gdb.  I'm not sure I understand the locality, but I'm in US, Central Time.

Comment: Maybe you can play around with the format string (`FMT`), have a look [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior) or you could use python string slicing to trim off the last 3 characters?